Issue with Second User Not Adding to Convex Database
Running into a snag with my project setup—leveraging Clerk for authentication & Convex for the DB. Oddly, the second user's not getting added in Convex, even though Clerk's updating smoothly. Any ideas on a fix?
I attempted to add a user to Convex, the database in my project, following the process outlined. However, despite Clerk smoothly updating, the second user didn't get added to Convex as expected. I'm now seeking insights or suggestions to resolve this issue.

Facing a significant challenge with Clerk's webhook where 98% of requests fail due to null first_name values when users log in via email instead of Google. This issue arises from an exclamation point in the code that overlooks null values. The solution involves updating the code to handle null values properly by either modifying the event data line to name: event.data.first_name ?? "" or adjusting the schema definitions with v.union(v.string(), v.null()) in createUser and podcasts schemas. Grateful for the guidance and support from the Convex community and Mr. Lee in resolving this critical issue.
